# Convert an IPv6 address to an encoded string and back in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, ipv6

How do you convert an IPv6 address into a binary representation and back?

I was only able to convert it to a number, then attempting to convert that to a string.

```
IPAddr.new('fe80::c')
# => #<IPAddr: IPv6:fe80:0000:0000:0000:0000:0000:0000:000c/ffff:ffff:ffff:ffff:ffff:ffff:ffff:ffff>

IPAddr.new('fe80::c').to_i
# => 338288524927261089654018896841347694604
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As @tadman pointed out, dealing with it as a number doesn't make sense. Converting it to binary is ideal.

Convert from **IPv6 to bytes**:

```
IPAddr.new('fe80::c').hton
# => "\xFE\x80\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\f"
```

Convert from **bytes to IPv6**:

```
IPAddr::new_ntoh(_)
# => #<IPAddr: IPv6:fe80:0000:0000:0000:0000:0000:0000:000c/ffff:ffff:ffff:ffff:ffff:ffff:ffff:ffff>
```

Comment: Dealing with the binary representation of the address makes sense. Representing it as a number doesn't, really.

Answer (score 0):

It's not the most elegant solution, I'm sure, but seems to work for me:

```
 my_ip = IPAddr.new('fe80::c').to_i.to_s(16)
```

This gives you a string with the full expanded IPv6 address in hex form.

The following function can then be used to convert the hex string to
binary:

```
 def hex_to_bin(s_h) # convert readable hex to binary
     s_h.scan(/../).map { |z| z.hex.chr }.join
 end
```